# Running Kibana gives "version_conflict_engine_exception"

Tags: kibana

When I try to run kibana, I get the below error. How can i solve it ?

```
    [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:Lens-lens_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [4])
    [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:Actions-actions_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [4])
    [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:apm-telemetry-task]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [4])
    [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:Alerting-alerting_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [4])
    [error][data][elasticsearch] [version_conflict_engine_exception]: [task:endpoint:user-artifact-packager:1.0.0]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [7])
    [info][listening] Server running at http://localhost:5601
    [info][server][Kibana][http] http server running at http://localhost:5601
    [warning][plugins][reporting] Enabling the Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection.
```

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"
The source of these errors is normal. This can be reproduced by starting Kibana a second time against the same Elasticsearch cluster.

This happens because on each startup of Kibana, some telemetry tasks ensure they are scheduled by calling the saved object's create API and ignoring 409 manually (meaning the task already exists). It seems the Elasticsearch layer in between logs any errors that are thrown.
"

ref:

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/77903

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/84447